# configure SVN for Flash Action script programming

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am working as a Action Script programmer, and am included in team, the size of the team is 3. So we are working in the same shared files, the we are having a lot of conflict in the **fla** file and **AS** files. I wish to implement the SVN for our project. So is that can be done in **TortoiseSVN** , then how can i configure in LAN. We are in Windows platform.
So any one know how to configure SVN for Flash Programming please please help me out..

Answer (score 0):

1. For very easy server installation use [VisualSVN server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/) (Windows Only), you can built your svn server with it in less than 10 Min.
2. Use the VisualSvn server admin tool, to define your project, team users and permissions, it's very easy task too.
3. Install TortoiseSVN on each client machine, and Checkout your files to the project name you defined on SVN server, for example it will look like

   > http://mysvnserver:8080/svn/MyFlashProject/
4. Add your files inside that folder (the on client machine), TortoiseSVN will show you some icons, add the files you want to be included on the project to share with the team, if you have local temp files or whatever that only specific for you machine, you can add them to your igonre list.
5. Right click and use commit, now it's the version revision that each user can be updated on his machine.

that's all :-)